# Convert TWO text boxes into a list box on another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox, listbox

I have a list box on Form1 (main form)

I have three text boxes on Form2.

The first text box is a Name Entry, while the second prompts an input for an integer between 0 and 100, and after entering a number it is sent to the third (read only) text box where that persons scores are shown.

How do I code these to accomplish:
Having the Name with their scores together in the list box on Form1.

Ex:
Form2
Name: Jane Doe
Score: ___    AddScoreButton
Scores: 56 | 80 | 78

ACCEPTBUTTON   CANCELBUTTON

The accept button needs to send the Name and Scores text boxes data to the list on Form1 and be in the same line:

Form1
ListStudents:
Jane Doe | 56 | 80 | 78

The “|” is needed.

I also have to find the total sum and average of each persons scores but I have already figured that part out.

SORRY FOR THE LACK OF IMAGES I AM NOT HOME BUT STILL TRYING TO FIGURE THIS CODE OUT FOR A SCHOOL PROJECT DUE SUNDAY!

I tried to send some generic sample people with scores but I received:
“Jane Doe | Sysyems.collections.Generic.List’1[Int32]]

Instead of:
“Jane Doe | 56 | 80 | 78”

I am not home right now I will provide my exact code when I am.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather general question, but see if this helps get you on the way

i would create a student class with a Name and a list Scores
then override the ToString() of that class, like:

```
public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} | {string.Join(" | ",Scores)}";
        }
```

you can put these student objects in the items collection of the listbox

but you have to get the response back to the main form

Or use an event raised on form2 that you subscribe to on form1
or pass a reference to form1 when you create form2 and use that to pass it along